# Get the Json from SOQL Query in Salesforce for EXTJS Combobox

Tags: extjs, salesforce, apex-code

Is there any possible to bind the EXTJS combobox with SOQL Query results directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXTJS Combobox gets values from [Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) that can be populated by ajax creating a visualforce page that return JSON with the results of your SOQL query (slow). 
Or it can be populated using a [JS Remoting](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm)  function call (fast), [just adding values to the store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-add) asynchronously.

It would be something like this (code not tested, just illustrative):

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : []
});

// you can use promises to show a loader for the combo box
var statesLoaded = $.Deferred();

Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.PremadeClassWithSOQL.getStates}',
            function(resultInJSON){
               states.add(JSON.parse(resultInJSON));
               statesLoaded.done();
            }
        );

// when promise ready
$.when(statesLoaded){
  // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
  Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
  });
}
```